# AngularJS resource: Send query parameter only if non-empty

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a Angularjs resource and in one of the methods, I want to send a query parameter to the backend if that query parameter is non-empty. Is it possible to achieve that without created a different method?

Example resource method:

```
get: {
      method: 'GET',
      url: /api/:token?source=:source,
      paramSerializer: someSerializer
    },
```

The code to call the method is,

```
myResource.get({token: '1234'}, {source: <some source>});
```

The token is required, but the source is optional, so sometimes it is not passed in to the call above. So if a value is provided for the source, I want to be able to send the source. If the source value is not provided, I want to not send the source at all. For instance, the call will become /api/1234 if source is empty, and the call will become /api/1234?source=some_source if the source is set as some_source.

With the code above, if the source is empty, I see that the request is '/api/1234?source=' when the source is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the url template without the extra parameters:

```
get: {
      method: 'GET',
      url: "/api/:token",
    },
```

Then add the extra parameters when invoking the action:

```
myResource.get({token: '1234', source: <some source>});
```

The extra parameters will be automatically added to the url as query parameters.

From the Docs:

> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search query after the `?`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $resource API Reference - Arguments](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#$resource-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass query params via get.params{} then AngularJS will automatically handled stripping out undefined properties.

Comment: Thank you. I am not very familiar with this. If you could please tell me how to modify the myResource.get({token: '1234'}, {source: <some source>}); call, that would help. I will research as well, thanks again.